# How to get only one item of the a permutation from a list of strings

Tags: bash, scripts, awk, uniq

I want to keep only one permutation among a set of strings and count the  occurence of each permutation.

To make things more clear, I want to transform (for instance)

```
ab
acf
ba
cfa
acf
```

into

```
2 ab
3 acf
```

where 2 and 3 are the number of permutations of {a,b} and {a,c,f} respectively.

**How would you do it in bash in the straightest possible way?**

Comment: Is there any chance that any characters will be repeated within a single string? e.g. `abbc`

Comment: convert each string to a set of chars, or a sorted list of chars, and save that. In Python you could use itertools.permutations() to get all possible permutations (or number thereof).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -lne '$h{ join "", sort split // }++ }{ print "$h{$_} $_" for keys %h' < input_file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-l` removes newlines from input, adds newlines to output
- `split //` splits the string into characters
- `sort` sorts them (hence uniqueness)
- `join ""` creates back a single string from the list of characters
- `%h` is a hash table, keys are the strings of sorted characters, values are numbers of occurrences: increased (`++`) on each encounter
- `}{` "Eskimo greeting" - separates the code to run after the input is exhausted